# Nonlinear Least Squares in R - Levenberg Marquardt to Fit Heligman Pollard Model Parameters

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization, model-fitting, levenberg-marquardt

I am attempting to reproduce the solutions of paper by Kostakis. In this paper an abridged mortality table is expanded to a complete life table using de Heligman-Pollard model. The model has 8 parameters which have to be fitted. The author used a modified Gauss-Newton algorithm; this algorithm (E04FDF) is part of the NAG library of computer programs. Should not Levenberg Marquardt yield the same set of parameters? What is wrong with my code or application of the LM algorithm?

```
library(minpack.lm)


## Heligman-Pollard is used to expand an abridged table.
## nonlinear least squares algorithm is used to fit the parameters on nqx observed over 5 year   intervals (5qx)
AGE <- c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70)
MORTALITY <- c(0.010384069, 0.001469140, 0.001309318, 0.003814265, 0.005378395, 0.005985625,     0.006741766, 0.009325056, 0.014149626, 0.021601755, 0.034271934, 0.053836246, 0.085287751, 0.136549522, 0.215953304)

## The start parameters for de Heligman-Pollard Formula (Converged set a=0.0005893,b=0.0043836,c=0.0828424,d=0.000706,e=9.927863,f=22.197312,g=0.00004948,h=1.10003)
## I modified a random parameter "a" in order to have a start values. The converged set is listed above. 
parStart <- list(a=0.0008893,b=0.0043836,c=0.0828424,d=0.000706,e=9.927863,f=22.197312,g=0.00004948,h=1.10003)

## The Heligman-Pollard Formula (HP8) = qx/px = ...8 parameter equation
HP8 <-function(parS,x)
ifelse(x==0, parS$a^((x+parS$b)^parS$c) + parS$g*parS$h^x, 
             parS$a^((x+parS$b)^parS$c) + parS$d*exp(-parS$e*(log(x/parS$f))^2) +
                 parS$g*parS$h^x)

## Define qx = HP8/(1+HP8)
qxPred <- function(parS,x) HP8(parS,x)/(1+HP8(parS,x))

## Calculate nqx predicted by HP8 model (nqxPred(parStart,x))
nqxPred <- function(parS,x)
(1 -(1-qxPred(parS,x)) * (1-qxPred(parS,x+1)) *
    (1-qxPred(parS,x+2)) * (1-qxPred(parS,x+3)) *
    (1-qxPred(parS,x+4))) 

##Define Residual Function, the relative squared distance is minimized  
ResidFun <- function(parS, Observed,x) (nqxPred(parS,x)/Observed-1)^2

## Applying the nls.lm algo. 
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, fn = ResidFun, Observed = MORTALITY, x = AGE,
                  control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1,
                                           ftol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           ptol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           maxfev=10000, maxiter = 500))

summary(nls.out)


## The author used a modified Gauss-Newton algorithm, this alogorithm (E04FDF) is part of the NAG library of computer programs
## Should not Levenberg Marquardt yield the same set of parameters
```

Comment: Carriage returns are your friend.

Comment: @HongOoi, not anymore.

Comment: “With four parameters, I can fit an elephant, and with five, I can make him wiggle his trunk.” ([John von Neumann](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_von_Neumann)) I believe this is serious case of overfitting. There are probably numerous local minima and other nasties. Make some diagnostic plots to check parameter sensitivity. If you have such problems different algorithms can give different results. Btw., why don't you use the `nlsLM` frontend?

Comment: @Roland, it is a known mortality law model

Comment: Doesn't change my point.

Comment: I saw your deleted update to my question. We should probably continue this conversation elsewhere, since it's not really a programming question any more. It's true that the parameters from the original paper do a better job fitting the *full* data set, but that's not the point -- they do a worse job fitting the abridged data set, which is all you'd have to work with in the intended use case ...

Comment: @BenBolker I am sorry for deleting anything. I am very clumsy with this site. It takes getting just I geuss. Editing the code ect takes me ages.

Comment: you didn't delete it -- other site participants with revision authority decided it wasn't appropriate.  You could try posting as an answer ...

Answer (score 13):

The bottom line here is that @Roland is absolutely right, this is a very ill-posed problem, and you shouldn't necessarily expect to get reliable answers.  Below I've

- cleaned up the code in a few small ways (this is just aesthetic)
- changed the `ResidFun` to return residuals, not squared residuals.  (The former is correct, but this doesn't make very much difference.)
- explored results from several different optimizers.  It actually looks like the answer you're getting is *better* than the "converged parameters" you list above, which I'm assuming are the parameters from the original study (can you please provide a reference?).

Load package:

```
library(minpack.lm)
```

Data, as a data frame:

```
d <- data.frame(
   AGE = seq(0,70,by=5),
   MORTALITY=c(0.010384069, 0.001469140, 0.001309318, 0.003814265,
               0.005378395, 0.005985625, 0.006741766, 0.009325056,
               0.014149626, 0.021601755, 0.034271934, 0.053836246,
               0.085287751, 0.136549522, 0.215953304))
```

First view of the data:

```
library(ggplot2)
(g1 <- ggplot(d,aes(AGE,MORTALITY))+geom_point())
g1+geom_smooth()  ## with loess fit
```

Parameter choices:

Presumably these are the parameters from the original paper ...

```
parConv <- c(a=0.0005893,b=0.0043836,c=0.0828424,
             d=0.000706,e=9.927863,f=22.197312,g=0.00004948,h=1.10003)
```

Perturbed parameters:

```
parStart <- parConv
parStart["a"] <- parStart["a"]+3e-4
```

The formulae:

```
HP8 <-function(parS,x)
    with(as.list(parS),
         ifelse(x==0, a^((x+b)^c) + g*h^x, 
                a^((x+b)^c) + d*exp(-e*(log(x/f))^2) + g*h^x))
## Define qx = HP8/(1+HP8)
qxPred <- function(parS,x) {
    h <- HP8(parS,x)
    h/(1+h)
}
## Calculate nqx predicted by HP8 model (nqxPred(parStart,x))
nqxPred <- function(parS,x)
    (1 -(1-qxPred(parS,x)) * (1-qxPred(parS,x+1)) *
     (1-qxPred(parS,x+2)) * (1-qxPred(parS,x+3)) *
     (1-qxPred(parS,x+4))) 
##Define Residual Function, the relative squared distance is minimized  
ResidFun <- function(parS, Observed,x) (nqxPred(parS,x)/Observed-1)
```

n.b. this is changed slightly from the OP's version; `nls.lm` wants residuals, not squared residuals.

A sum-of-squares function for use with other optimizers:

```
ssqfun <- function(parS, Observed, x) {
   sum(ResidFun(parS, Observed, x)^2)
}
```

Applying `nls.lm`. (Not sure why `ftol`  and `ptol` were lowered
from `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` to `.Machine$double.eps` -- the
former is generally a *practical* limit to precision ...

```
nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, fn = ResidFun,
                  Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE,
                  control = nls.lm.control(nprint=0,
                                           ftol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           ptol = .Machine$double.eps,
                                           maxfev=10000, maxiter = 1000))

parNLS <- coef(nls.out)

pred0 <- nqxPred(as.list(parConv),d$AGE)
pred1 <- nqxPred(as.list(parNLS),d$AGE)

dPred <- with(d,rbind(data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred0,w="conv"),
               data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred1,w="nls")))

g1 + geom_line(data=dPred,aes(colour=w))
```

The lines are indistinguishable, but the parameters have some big
differences:

```
round(cbind(parNLS,parConv),5)
##     parNLS  parConv
## a  1.00000  0.00059
## b 50.46708  0.00438
## c  3.56799  0.08284
## d  0.00072  0.00071
## e  6.05200  9.92786
## f 21.82347 22.19731
## g  0.00005  0.00005
## h  1.10026  1.10003
```

d,f,g,h are close, but a,b,c are orders of magnitude different and e is 50% different.

Looking at the original equations, what's happening here is that `a^((x+b)^c)` is getting set to a constant, because `a` is approaching 1: once `a` is approximately 1, `b` and `c` are essentially irrelevant.

Let's check the correlation (we need a generalized inverse because
the matrix is so strongly correlated):

```
obj <- nls.out
vcov  <- with(obj,deviance/(length(fvec) - length(par)) * 
              MASS::ginv(hessian))

cmat <- round(cov2cor(vcov),1)
dimnames(cmat) <- list(letters[1:8],letters[1:8])

##      a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h
## a  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0 -0.1  0.0
## b  0.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -0.4 -1.0
## c  0.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  1.0  0.4  1.0
## d  0.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -0.4 -1.0
## e  0.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  1.0  0.4  1.0
## f  0.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  1.0  0.4  1.0
## g -0.1 -0.4  0.4 -0.4  0.4  0.4  1.0  0.4
## h  0.0 -1.0  1.0 -1.0  1.0  1.0  0.4  1.0
```

This is not actually so useful -- it really just confirms that lots
of the variables are strongly correlated ...

```
library(optimx)
mvec <- c('Nelder-Mead','BFGS','CG','L-BFGS-B',
          'nlm','nlminb','spg','ucminf')
opt1 <- optimx(par=parStart, fn = ssqfun,
         Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE,
               itnmax=5000,
               method=mvec,control=list(kkt=TRUE))
               ## control=list(all.methods=TRUE,kkt=TRUE)) ## Boom!

##         fvalues      method fns  grs itns conv KKT1 KKT2 xtimes
## 2 8.988466e+307        BFGS  NA NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA      0
## 3 8.988466e+307          CG  NA NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA      0
## 4 8.988466e+307    L-BFGS-B  NA NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA      0
## 5 8.988466e+307         nlm  NA   NA   NA 9999   NA   NA      0
## 7     0.3400858         spg   1   NA    1    3   NA   NA  0.064
## 8     0.3400858      ucminf   1    1 NULL    0   NA   NA  0.032
## 1    0.06099295 Nelder-Mead 501   NA NULL    1   NA   NA  0.252
## 6   0.009275733      nlminb 200 1204  145    1   NA   NA  0.708
```

This warns about bad scaling, and also finds a variety of different
answers: only `ucminf` claims to have converged, but `nlminb` gets a
better answer -- and the `itnmax` parameter seems to be ignored ...

```
opt2 <- nlminb(start=parStart, objective = ssqfun,
         Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE,                   
               control= list(eval.max=5000,iter.max=5000))

parNLM <- opt2$par
```

Finishes, but with a false convergence warning ...

```
round(cbind(parNLS,parConv,parNLM),5)

##     parNLS  parConv   parNLM
## a  1.00000  0.00059  1.00000
## b 50.46708  0.00438 55.37270
## c  3.56799  0.08284  3.89162
## d  0.00072  0.00071  0.00072
## e  6.05200  9.92786  6.04416
## f 21.82347 22.19731 21.82292
## g  0.00005  0.00005  0.00005
## h  1.10026  1.10003  1.10026

sapply(list(parNLS,parConv,parNLM),
       ssqfun,Observed=d$MORTALITY,x=d$AGE)
## [1] 0.006346250 0.049972367 0.006315034
```

It looks like `nlminb` and `minpack.lm` are getting similar answers, and are actually doing *better* than the originally stated parameters (by quite a bit):

```
pred2 <- nqxPred(as.list(parNLM),d$AGE)

dPred <- with(d,rbind(dPred,
               data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred2,w="nlminb")))

g1 + geom_line(data=dPred,aes(colour=w))
ggsave("cmpplot.png")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data=dPred,aes(x=AGE,y=MORTALITY-d$MORTALITY,colour=w))+
   geom_line()+geom_point(aes(shape=w),alpha=0.3)
ggsave("residplot.png")
```

[image]

Other things one could try would be:

- appropriate scaling -- although a quick test of this doesn't seem to help that much
- provide analytical gradients
- use AD Model Builder
- use the `slice` function from `bbmle` to explore whether the old and new parameters seem to represent distinct minima, or whether the old parameters are just a false convergence ...
- get the KKT (Karsh-Kuhn-Tucker) criterion calculators from `optimx` or related packages working for similar checks

PS: the largest deviations (by far) are for the oldest age classes, which probably also have small samples.  From a statistical point of view it would probably be worth doing a fit that weighted by the precision of the individual points ...

Comment: I'm impressed.  It should be mentioned that you should have much more data, if you try to fit so many parameters. It would be best to estimate some of the parameters with independent additional experiments. The result oft the fit should preferably be validated with independent data or at least cross-validated.

Comment: @BenBolker, Thank you for the reply. I sent you the paper via email since I was unable to attach the paper. I got this paper from the "Journal of Official Statistics, Vol.7, No.3, 1991. pp. 311–323" Title:

Comment: @BenBolker                                                     Title: The Heligman-Pollard Formula as a Tool for Expanding an Abridged Life Table

Author: Anastasia Kostaki

Link: http://www.jos.nu/Articles/abstract.asp?article=73311

Comment: Thanks for the paper.  I will take a look, if I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

@BenBolker, fitting the parameters with the entire dataset (underlying qx) values. Still not able to reproduce parameters

```
library(minpack.lm)

library(ggplot2)

library(optimx)

getwd()

d <- data.frame(AGE = seq(0,74), MORTALITY=c(869,58,40,37,36,35,32,28,29,23,24,22,24,28,
                                           33,52,57,77,93,103,103,109,105,114,108,112,119,
                                           125,117,127,125,134,134,131,152,179,173,182,199,
                                           203,232,245,296,315,335,356,405,438,445,535,594,
                                           623,693,749,816,915,994,1128,1172,1294,1473,
                                           1544,1721,1967,2129,2331,2559,2901,3203,3470,
                                           3782,4348,4714,5245,5646))


d$MORTALITY <- d$MORTALITY/100000

ggplot(d,aes(AGE,MORTALITY))+geom_point()  

##Not allowed to post Images

g1 <- ggplot(d,aes(AGE,MORTALITY))+geom_point()

g1+geom_smooth()## with loess fit
```

Reported Parameters:

```
parConv <- c(a=0.0005893,b=0.0043836,c=0.0828424,d=0.000706,e=9.927863,f=22.197312,
             g=0.00004948,h=1.10003)

parStart <- parConv

parStart["a"] <- parStart["a"]+3e-4


## Define qx = HP8/(1+HP8)

HP8 <-function(parS,x)
with(as.list(parS),
ifelse(x==0, a^((x+b)^c) + g*h^x, a^((x+b)^c) + d*exp(-e*(log(x/f))^2) + g*h^x))



qxPred <- function(parS,x) {
  h <- HP8(parS,x)
  h/(1+h)
}



##Define Residual Function, the relative squared distance is minimized,
ResidFun <- function(parS, Observed,x) (qxPred(parS,x)/Observed-1)

ssqfun <- function(parS, Observed, x) {
  sum(ResidFun(parS, Observed, x)^2)
}

nls.out <- nls.lm(par=parStart, fn = ResidFun, Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE, 
                  control = nls.lm.control(nprint=1, ftol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), 
                  ptol = sqrt(.Machine$double.eps), maxfev=1000, maxiter=1000))


parNLS <- coef(nls.out)

pred0 <- qxPred(as.list(parConv),d$AGE)
pred1 <- qxPred(as.list(parNLS),d$AGE)


#Binds Row wise the dataframes from pred0 and pred1
dPred <- with(d,rbind(data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred0,w="conv"),
      data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred1,w="nls")))


g1 + geom_line(data=dPred,aes(colour=w))

round(cbind(parNLS,parConv),7)

mvec <- c('Nelder-Mead','BFGS','CG','L-BFGS-B','nlm','nlminb','spg','ucminf')
opt1 <- optimx(par=parStart, fn = ssqfun,
    Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE,
    itnmax=5000,
    method=mvec, control=list(all.methods=TRUE,kkt=TRUE,)
## control=list(all.methods=TRUE,kkt=TRUE)) ## Boom

get.result(opt1, attribute= c("fvalues","method", "grs", "itns",
           "conv", "KKT1", "KKT2", "xtimes"))

##       method       fvalues  grs itns conv KKT1 KKT2 xtimes
##5         nlm 8.988466e+307   NA   NA 9999   NA   NA      0
##4    L-BFGS-B 8.988466e+307 NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA      0
##2          CG 8.988466e+307 NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA   0.02
##1        BFGS 8.988466e+307 NULL NULL 9999   NA   NA      0
##3 Nelder-Mead     0.5673864   NA NULL    0   NA   NA   0.42
##6      nlminb     0.4127198  546   62    0   NA   NA   0.17


opt2 <- nlminb(start=parStart, objective = ssqfun,
    Observed = d$MORTALITY, x = d$AGE,
    control= list(eval.max=5000,iter.max=5000))

parNLM <- opt2$par
```

Check on parameters:

```
round(cbind(parNLS,parConv,parNLM),5)

##    parNLS  parConv   parNLM
##a  0.00058  0.00059  0.00058
##b  0.00369  0.00438  0.00369
##c  0.08065  0.08284  0.08065
##d  0.00070  0.00071  0.00070
##e  9.30948  9.92786  9.30970
##f 22.30769 22.19731 22.30769
##g  0.00005  0.00005  0.00005
##h  1.10084  1.10003  1.10084
```

SSE Review:

```
sapply(list(parNLS,parConv,parNLM),
  ssqfun,Observed=d$MORTALITY,x=d$AGE)  

 ##[1] 0.4127198 0.4169513 0.4127198
```

Not able to upload graphs but the code is here. Still appears that the parameters found in the article are not the best fit when the complete mortality data (not abridged or subset) is used

```
##pred2 <- qxPred(as.list(parNLM),d$AGE)

##dPred <- with(d,rbind(dPred,
    data.frame(AGE,MORTALITY=pred2,w="nlminb")))

##g1 + geom_line(data=dPred,aes(colour=w))
ggplot(data=dPred,aes(x=AGE,y=MORTALITY-d$MORTALITY,colour=w))
        + geom_line()+geom_point(aes(shape=w),alpha=0.3)
```

Comment: @BenStolker, I provide you int he answer with the complete dataset.